Android Fragment LiveData only updates after screen rotation or configuration change - using Java
I’m building an Android app that displays weather data fetched from an API. I’m using WeatherViewModel and LiveData to retain the data across configuration changes and ensure it’s displayed in WeatherFragment. However, I’ve run into an issue where the TextView in the fragment only updates with the weather data after a screen rotation or other configuration change.
When I click the "Fetch Weather" button, I want the TextView to immediately display the fetched weather data, but it currently remains blank until I rotate the screen or cause a configuration change.
Code Setup:
WeatherFragment.java:
In this fragment, I initialize WeatherViewModel and observe getWeatherData() in onViewCreated.
On button click, I call weatherViewModel.fetchWeatherData(city) to retrieve data based on user input.
public class WeatherFragment extends Fragment {

    private WeatherViewModel weatherViewModel;
    private FragmentWeatherBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentWeatherBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        weatherViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WeatherViewModel.class);

        binding.buttonFetchWeather.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String city = binding.editTextCity.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!city.isEmpty()) {
                weatherViewModel.fetchWeatherData(city); // Retrieve weather data for the city
            } else {
                binding.textViewWeather.setText("Please enter a city name.");
            }
        });

        weatherViewModel.getWeatherData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), weatherData -> {
            if (weatherData != null) {
                binding.textViewWeather.setText(weatherData);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null; // Avoid memory leaks
    }
}


WeatherViewModel.java:
In WeatherViewModel, I call fetchWeatherData(city) to trigger the API call and set the result in a MutableLiveData.
package com.example.weather;

import android.util.Log;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class WeatherViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final WeatherRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<String> weatherResult = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public WeatherViewModel() {
        repository = new WeatherRepository();
    }

    public void fetchWeatherData(String city) {
        weatherResult = repository.getWeather(city);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getWeather() {
        return weatherResult;
    }
}


What I’ve Tried:
Moved the observer for getWeatherData() to onCreateView, but the behavior is the same.
Question:
Why does LiveData only trigger an update after a configuration change, and how can I make sure the TextView updates immediately when I click the button? Is the issue related to asynchronous behavior in fetchWeatherData(city), and if so, how can I make it trigger an immediate update?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Your WeatherRepository method getWeather(city) should return just String.
And fetchWeatherDate(city) method should look like:
public void fetchWeatherData(String city) {
    String weatherString = repository.getWeather(city);
    weatherResult.setValue(weatherString);
}

